# How to add Tags in text node with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, tags, nodes

This is probably very easy/obvious.
I'm writing a Chrome extention.
My Javascript catches the text nodes from any site and changes part of the text to something else. I would like to mark the changed text by changing its color (adding tags).

```
return "<font color = \"FF0000\">"+a+"</font>"
```

And the result:

```
<font color = "FF0000">SomeText</font>
```

But all I want of course is that the **SomeText** will appear in red.

Comment: Font tags? really? they are deprecated since like a decade.

Comment: ThiefMaster: I didn't touched HTML for ages and thank you for your helpful comment. Salman: It is right there in the first code line..

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use CSS in your chrome extension. so my solution would involve giving the DOM element (for your instance maybe its a paragraph or a span) a class. It's not good conventions to put style attributes in your HTML markup.

```
<p class="red">SomeText</p>
```

And in your CSS file

```
.red {
    color: #ff0000 /* I actually love this color */
}
```

**So how does this use JavaScript?**

Instead of adding the styles directly into the HTML tag, you can instead add a class to an element.

```
document.getElementByTagName("p").className = "red";
```

Or if you want to target a specific ID

```
document.getElementById("object").className = "red";
```

And that text will be red. And since you can add the red class to any class attribute for any object in the DOM, your code will look cleaner than throwing styles everywhere.

I hope this helps you out. Let me know if otherwise.

Comment: The question is tagged JavaScript. And you should have posted the suggestion as a comment.

Comment: You're right, let me make some changes to improve the answer.

Comment: Can I create the CSS class dynamically (in the JS function) instead of using a file? And what if the DOM element already has a class? will it change it or just add to it?

Comment: your naming conventions are completely under the control. And DOM elements can have multiple classes, for example class="car inactive" has two classes, car and inactive.

Comment: but you'll have to do className += "red"  - This process is a lot easier with jQuery addClass(); and removeClass(); and yes you can use jQuery in your chrome extension too.

Answer (score 1):

```
function newText(tag, text, style) {
    var element = document.createElement(tag);              //this creates an empty node of the type specified
    element.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));     //this creates a new text node and inserts it into our empty node
    if (style) element.setAttribute('style', style);        //this sets the style in inline CSS (warning, this needs different syntax in IE)
    return element;                                         //this returns a DOM object
}
```

This will return a DOM object, and you will need to append it to another node.

```
var myText = newText('p', 'This is some text!', 'color: red;');
document.getElementById('myTextBox').appendChild(myText);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add color in your style sheet...
Like `<input type="text" style="color:red" value="sometext"/>`.